# Crystal Report not working for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, 32-bit

I have downloaded and installed Crystal Report "CRforVS_13_0_4.exe"  for Visual Studio 2010, professional edition. But it not seems to work with visual Studio. Whenever i try to open Tool Box window, OR try to add Crystal Report (.rpt) in to the project It gives me following error.

[Window Title]
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

[Main Instruction]
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 has stopped working

[Content]
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.

[Close the program] [Debug the program]

I checked that as soon as "Crystal Reports Tool Package" loads in to the Tool Box this error pop out.  I also monitored the files while installation and found that it seems that its 64 bit version.  But i am haveing 32 bit win7 OS. But i couldn't find out 32 bit version.
I installed "CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_3.zip"  but, it not support designer. and i got .mhtml extension while adding crystal report(.rpt)

Thanks.Any input will be appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more search I downloaded the latest version of Crystal Reports for VS2010 (Support Pack 5 (v. 13.0.5.x)) and it worked fine for me. Here is the link to download crystal reports

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

As mentioned on the website - "To integrate "SAP Crystal Reports, the developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio" into VS 2010 or 2012, you must run the Install Executable. Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only."

Comment: Where did you get install executable? There are only msi files for download on the link you provided. Kindly reply urgently